# how to get multidimensional array inner key of same values in php at once?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I had an array $data_rows

```
            array(3) {
               [0]=>
                    array(3) {
                           ["ID"]=>
                            string(4) "C102"
                           ["FName"]=>
                            string(4) "John"
                           ["City"]=>
                            string(7) "Newyork"
                     }
               [1]=>
                    array(3) {
                           ["ID"]=>
                            string(4) "C104"
                           ["FName"]=>
                            string(6) "Ramesh"
                           ["City"]=>
                            string(6) "Mumbai"
                     }
               [2]=>
                    array(3) {
                           ["ID"]=>
                            string(4) "C105"
                           ["FName"]=>
                            string(6) "Yuwang"
                           ["City"]=>
                            string(7) "Beijing"
                     }
               }
```

I had tried with array_keys($data_rows), it gives only

`0,1,2`

What can i put to get all the inner keys only once i.e.

`ID,FName,City`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
print_r( array_keys( $data_rows[0] ) );
```